# Book on probability theory with sigma algebra

Tags: probability, measure-theory, reference-request

Please suggest or recommend a book on Probability theory emphasising on sigma algebra and with Kolmogorov’s axiomatic development.

Answer (score 1):

Measure Theory and Probability - Adams, Guillemin